# Windows 7 Ultimate on Asus EeePC 1001PX

Tags: windows-7, drivers, wifi-driver, eee-pc

I have a Asus EeePC 1001PX and upgraded to Win 7 Ultimate but I couldn't find any driver for the wireless network adapter. Does anyone knows where I can find it?

Tried the official page of the Asus but NONE of the files helped me.

UPDATE:

[image]

or Everest info:

[image]

Comment: What is the hardware ID of the wireless adapter? (Check via the device manager, the [unidentified device, properties, tab "details", Property "Hardware Ids").

Comment: @Hennes: Please re-check my question I've updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCI vendor 168C is Atheros Communications Inc.
(I used [this database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) to search in, but any search engine should get you started.)

Refining the search their device 0032 yields:

```
Chip Number:      0x0209  
Chip Description: AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter  
Notes: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePC/Driver/AzurewaveWireless-V9_2_0_480.zip
```

The [zip file](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePC/Driver/AzurewaveWireless-V9_2_0_480.zip) in their notes seems to be for a "Qualcomm Atheros WiFi Driver Installation", "ProductGUID=7D916FA5-DAE9-4A25-B089-655C70EAF607", "CompanyName=Qualcomm Atheros". Try installing that one.

Comment: For future reference: This trick should work for almost any unidentified device. Both in windows (via the device manager) and in unix like OS's (e.g. OS/X) where you have commands such as `lspci` and `pciconf`

Comment: yes, this works, but be aware that sometimes you also need to install drivers for keyboard in order to be able to turn on wifi !